# How do I convert a table into a function?

Tags: plotting, evaluation

If I have this table which produce a list of paires of numbers.

```
ref2A = Table[{x, GWR[fun2A, t0, NTerms, 0.001]}, {x, 0, nn, 0.005}]
```

How can I Calculate (plot)the function

```
f[x_, t_] := (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 2*k*ref2A[x, t]])/k
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try interpolating the table in order to define your function:

```
f[x_] = (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 2*k*Interpolation[ref2A][x]])/k;
```

(I've assumed that ref2A and k were assigned numerical values before defining this function)

Comment: Thank you very much dan7geo. It is working now. Appreciate.

Comment: Glad to help...!

Comment: Hi dan7geo: I got this result:

Comment: What result exactly?